# Websphere 7.X. Set enabled connections to JMX via RMI

Tags: java, websphere, rmi, jmx, websphere-7

How to enable JMX connection via RMI in Websphere 7.x? 
I have a requirement:

> So the server has to enabled for JMX connection via RMI.

Is server has enabled JMX connections via RMI by default?
Or I must change in `Application servers > server1 > Administration services` value **Remote connector** from *SOAPConnetor* to *RMIConnector* and change value **Local connector**  from *IPC Connector* to *RMIConnector*?

Answer (score 0):

The RMI connector is enabled by default (in the sense that any WebSphere instance accepts JMX connections via RMI). The purpose of the "Local connector" and "Remote connector" settings under "Administration services" is different: they determine the protocol that is used between WebSphere instances.